# JQuery Mobile and MVC 3 or (MVC 4 beta) date validation format issue

Tags: jquery, validation, mobile, date

I'm using MVC 4 Beta, but I believe this will also apply to MVC 3.

I have a model defined as:

```
public class MealViewModel
{
[Required]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Required]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public bool Type { get; set; }
}
```

I have thoroughly read the JQM documentation and setup a JQM page properly.
It has a div with data-role="page", etc.
In that page is a form. In that form is a field of type date. Below is a snippet from the form.

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBox("Date",null,new{type="Date"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
</div>
```

I test the page on an iphone and it looks great and works perfect. With all fields blank I submit the form and as expected it validates the required fields. Whats particularly nice about JQM is that when I touch a date input field it automatically pops up the iphone date input keyboard and enters today's date to start. This is great. I accept the date and resubmit the form.

Now this is when I run into the validation issue. It renders a message "The field Date must be a date" The format of the date on the IOS is "Mar 16, 2012. JQuery validation must be expecting the date in another format.

How can I change the format so "Mar 16, 2012" is a valid date? The change must work with MVC.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this in your jquery.validate.js

Orignal-->

```
return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
```

Correct-->

```
var d = new Date();
return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
```

The browser does not detect the current date and this is a known bug

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to feed in the format, i ran into a similar problem here is the code from my dateTime editor template.

note it uses :http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js

```
@model System.DateTime
@{
    var id = this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("");
    var name = this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("");


    <input name="@name" id="@id" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "flipbox","noButtonFocusMode": true, "dateFormat": "DD/mm/YYYY"}' value="@Model.Date.ToShortDateString()">
    }
```

if you play around with the dateFormat, it should suit your needs.